# How can I find Firefox code that opens "Add new Bookmark" window?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am writing a Firefox Add-on that is supposed to add new bookmarks. I am thinking of employing some of the functionality that is already present in the Mozilla Firefox browser. As I understand, the Firefox browser is written in XUL and the code is open source. How can I find the code that performs any specific action, like in this case when I click the context menu item "Bookmark this link" a window appears "New Bookmark", how can I find the code that opens this window?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Viewing and searching Mozilla source code online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Viewing_and_searching_Mozilla_source_code_online) - there currently are two online tools for searching through the Mozilla's code: DXR and MXR. The former is newer and more advanced, the latter is simpler and more mature. Using any of these:

1. Search for the label you're looking for: ["Bookmark this link"](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=Bookmark+this+link%22&redirect=false&case=false)
2. Find a localization file (usually `.dtd` or `.properties`), which maps an internal name to the human-readable label, in this case: [browser/locales/en-US/chrome/browser/browser.dtd](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/d9b1a9829c8ee2862955043f28183efa07de3d2b/browser/locales/en-US/chrome/browser/browser.dtd#497):

   ```
   ENTITY bookmarkThisLinkCmd.label      "Bookmark This Link">
   ```
3. Search for the internal name you found: [bookmarkThisLinkCmd.label](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?tree=mozilla-central&q=bookmarkThisLinkCmd.label&redirect=true)
4. Find the code that displays it in the UI, usually `.xul` or `.js*`, in this case [browser/base/content/browser-context.inc](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/d9b1a9829c8ee2862955043f28183efa07de3d2b/browser/base/content/browser-context.inc#93) - a file that's included in a number of XUL files via preprocessor. (Note that DXR also shows you a bunch of results under `obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` - these are results generated during the build, and not the original source code, and should usually be ignored.)

   ```
     <menuitem id="context-bookmarklink"
           label="&bookmarkThisLinkCmd.label;"
           accesskey="&bookmarkThisLinkCmd.accesskey;"
           oncommand="gContextMenu.bookmarkLink();"/>
   ```
5. Find the definition of `gContextMenu`: [regexp:gContextMenu[^A-Za-z.]](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=regexp%3AgContextMenu%5B%5EA-Za-z.%5D&redirect=true&case=true) - there's a bunch of hits, all of them doing

   ```
    gContextMenu = new nsContextMenu(this, event.shiftKey);
   ```
6. Finally find the definition of `.bookmarkLink`: [browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#1690](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/d9b1a9829c8ee2862955043f28183efa07de3d2b/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#1690)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nickolay! That's an amazing answer. It would take me ages to figure it out on my own.