# Explanation of (undocumented?) XUL dialog attribute buttoniconaccept (and similar)

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am pulling this attribute directly from Mozilla Firefox's about.xul file which shows the **About** dialog box for an add-on.  It is a relatively simple XUL dialog with no inputs, locale data pulled from DTD entities, string bundle properties and JavaScript.

```
<!-- omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/content/mozapps/extensions/about.xul -->
<!-- chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/about.xul -->

<dialog id="genericAbout"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    onload="init();"
    buttons="accept"
    buttoniconaccept="close"
    onaccept="close();">
```

[MDN: Dialogs and Prompts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Dialogs_and_Prompts) and [MDN: dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/dialog) both mention something about attributes that are formed by concatenating (pseudo-regexp):

`"button" + "(label|accesskey|oncommand)" + "(accept|cancel|disclosure|help|extra[12])"`

For example: `buttonlabelaccept`.

However, I could not find any documentation about the use of `icon`.  The word `icon` does not even show up on either of the above-mentioned pages!  What does it do?  What is the correct way to use it?

I'm trying to make my add-on about page more modular, without loading internal files from omni.ja(r), which pulls in a LOT of unnecessary code with it.  I am developing a very streamlined version, that will style itself appropriately depending on calling context.

I want it to look like Firefox's official **About < addon.name >** dialog if called from about:addons context-menu, or from my add-on's status-bar context-menu.  I want a slightly different appearance if viewed from within the Options dialog as an iframe inside a XUL.  I already have that structure set up.  Just tweaking the little quirks.

This is not critical design or feature wise, and indeed the entire API will go away in a few months, but it just bothers me to not really understand this, so I want to figure it out before I let it go an move on to more important things.  But I will if I absolutely can't find an answer.  But it's one of those stupid little things that will just bother me a disproportionate amount.  =D

If you can point me to documentation I may have missed, or even specific Mozilla source code, and a few examples, or a more complete explanation and typical use-cases, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the ["blame"](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/ea15028498ed/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/about.xul#l12) for about.xul, you'll see that the line was [added](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/diff/1d18d830df74/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/about.xul#l50) to fix [bug 422763](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=422763). Judging from the screenshot in the bug, GNOME (Linux) has (had?) a convention of putting icons on dialog buttons, and this attribute allows overriding the default icon (inferred from the button type).

If you [search for buttonicon](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=buttonicon&find=&findi=&filter=%5E%5B%5E%5C0%5D*%24&hitlimit=&tree=mozilla-central), you'll find the [code that handles this attribute](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/ea15028498ed/toolkit/content/widgets/dialog.xml#l270) in `toolkit/content/widgets/dialog.xml`.

Comment: Another [example of searching through the moziilla's code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507832/how-can-i-find-firefox-code-that-opens-add-new-bookmark-window) might be useful, since you appear to like to dig into the details of how things work :)

Comment: Ok, thank you!  button + icon + (accept | cancel | disclosure | help | extra1 | extra2 ) I think are the possible value values.  I dig until I understand, or don't know how to dig anymore.  I love to stop digging when I read the first doc file because everything is explained wonderfully, allowing me to quickly and easily determine what code to write to achieve a task, but somet^H^H^H^H^Husually that is not the case.  ^_^